# how to update table based on another

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables `payment_scroll` and `virtual`
`virtual` table contains 4 fields...

```
ID  self_id    net_amount   date  
1    101         600        1-1-2012  
2    102         700        5-8-2012  
3    103         900        13-11-2012  
4    104         1100       16-9-2012
```

In `payment_scroll` table `net_amount` field is updated from gridview on front end. After update `net_amount` on same table

```
ID  self_id    net_amount   date  
1    101         950        3-4-2012  
2    102         1100       11-6-2012  
3    103         900        13-11-2012  
4    104         1100       16-9-2012
```

I want the to update the second table `payment_scroll` via `virtual` table like the below manner.

```
ID  self_id  total_amount  p1   d1      p2  d2    p3 d3 p4 d4..........upto p100   d100  
1    101      5000        600 (1-1-2012) 950  (3-4-2012)  
2    102      9650        700 (5-8-2012) 1100 (11-6-2012)  
3    103      8000        900 (13-11-2012)  
4    104      1100        1100 (16-9-2012)
```

please suggest me the right query to do this??

Comment: Do you want to create a new table with up to `p100` and `d100` as columns?

Comment: do you have more than 200 column in one table >?

Comment: just create payment_scroll table with foreign key related to virtual, if you mean this i can write for you the script

Comment: Tables shouldn't contain multiple columns containing data of the same "type". They become more difficult to query in a general fashion.

Comment: Actually, i mean to say that i want to create a payment scroll for each member in my scheme for that i have a table payment_scroll...in front end i use asp.net.payment_scroll table have all members records that at which date how much amount i give them for that i have column like p1,d1   p2,d2  etc now using gridview how to achive      this task so plz tell me the exact query to do this.........THANKS